# Loop to remove prefix in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a DF where some values have a prefix and I want to make a loop to remove it.
The DF looks like this:
[image]

I want to remove the "null-" and just leave the numbers.
I tried that, but I got and error message:
[image]

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Avoid lambda it is very slow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dataframe replace

```
 df = df.replace(to_replace=r'null-', value='', regex=True)
```

Comment: wwnde approach: `167 µs ± 6.97 µs`
mine: `1.47 ms ± 451 µs`
+1
but i think without `regex` is a bit better:
`84.5 µs ± 33.9 µs`

Comment: If performance is the main concern, though `replace()` is faster for very small dataframes (on the order of 100-1000 items), for larger dataframes the `applymap()`  approach is the winner. See my answer for benchmarking.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```py
df = df.applymap(lambda x: x if type(x) is not str or not x.startswith('null-') else x[len('null-'):])
```

Explanation:

- [`applymap()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) applies a function to every element in the DataFrame.
- The lambda above will work for heterogeneous data types (mix of numbers and strings, for example)

**UPDATE:**

Here's a benchmarking comparison of my `applymap()` based solution with a `replace()` solution such as the one in the answer by @wwnde:

[image]

As the image above shows, `replace()` is faster for very small dataframes (on the order of 100-1000 items), but for larger dataframes the `applymap()`  approach is the winner.

Comment: No need to use apply. It is very slow

Comment: @wwnde Note that I have used `applymap()`, not `apply()`. Though `replace()` is faster for very small dataframes (on the order of 100-1000 items), for larger dataframes the `applymap()`  approach is the winner. See my updated answer for benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace("null-",""))
```

or, if you only want to remove from start:

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.str.lstrip("null-"))
```

Comment: No need to use apply. It is very slow

Comment: @wwnde ok, thanks I learned a new thing although I answered it :)